# filtering ranges within nested arrays in BigQuery, and de-duping the result

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm playing with BigQuery and nested tables, and SQL is not my strong suit. I have a real problem with actual production data that I'm trying to solve, and at the same time trying to break-in some SQL/BQ concepts into my head.

My query is similar to some of what's on the [Working with Arrays in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) page, but similar is not close enough for me just yet.

Let me throw you some example data structured very similarly to my real data, then describe what I need out of it.

Basically, I have two tables, and I want to use one to filter the other.

Table 1 has some two-level nesting and can be built like this:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT "Test 1" AS name, [STRUCT(1 AS id, [20, 21] AS results), STRUCT(2 AS id, [22, 23] AS results)] AS resultset
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Test 2" AS name, [STRUCT(1 AS id, [23, 24] AS results), STRUCT(2 AS id, [25, 26] AS results)] AS resultset
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Test 3" AS name, [STRUCT(1 AS id, [26, 27] AS results), STRUCT(2 AS id, [28, 29] AS results)] AS resultset
)
SELECT * FROM data
```

What the numbers mean is irrelevant. What's important is that table 2 contains *ranges* that I want to use to filter table 1. Table 2 can be built like this:

```
ranges AS (
    SELECT "Range 1" AS title, 24.0 AS min, 25.0 AS max
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "Range 2" AS title, 26.0 AS min, 27.0 AS max
)
SELECT * from ranges
```

What I want to end up with is rows from the first table where **any** result matches one or more of the ranges in the second table, but none of the rows with no matches.

I know I can juggle some UNNEST()ing and JOINing of the two tables to get at a result which is filtered, but which will contain duplicates because of the unnesting:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT "Test 1" as name, [STRUCT(1 as id, [20, 21] as results), STRUCT(2 as id, [22, 23] as results)] as resultset
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Test 2" as name, [STRUCT(1 as id, [23, 24] as results), STRUCT(2 as id, [25, 26] as results)] as resultset
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Test 3" as name, [STRUCT(1 as id, [26, 27] as results), STRUCT(2 as id, [28, 29] as results)] as resultset
),
ranges AS (
  SELECT "Range 1" AS title, 24.0 as min, 25.0 as max
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "Range 2" AS title, 26.0 as min, 27.0 as max
)
SELECT data.*
FROM data, UNNEST(resultset), UNNEST(results) r
JOIN ranges
ON r BETWEEN min AND max
```

So this is what I have:

```
Row     name    resultset.id    resultset.results

1       Test 2             1                   23
                                               24
                           2                   25
                                               26

2       Test 2             1                   23
                                               24
                           2                   25
                                               26

3       Test 2             1                   23
                                               24
                           2                   25
                                               26

4       Test 3             1                   26
                                               27
                           2                   28
                                               29

5       Test 3             1                   26
                                               27
                           2                   28
                                               29
```

What I *want* is to call DISTINCT data.* in the SELECT to reduce this back down to the two unique rows and be done with it.

In other words, this is what I want:

```
Row     name    resultset.id    resultset.results

1       Test 2             1                   23
                                               24
                           2                   25
                                               26

2       Test 3             1                   26
                                               27
                           2                   28
                                               29
```

But I cannot do that with nested data.

So, I have two questions:

1. How do I collapse identical rows in this case?
2. Have I led myself up the wrong path, and is there a better way to achieve this?

Regarding the data: I cannot change the first table. The second table I can screw around with, if it leads to a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The simplest solution would be (w/o actually changing the core of query you already have) is to add GROUP BY as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ANY_VALUE(data).*
FROM data, UNNEST(resultset), UNNEST(results) r
JOIN ranges ON r BETWEEN min AND max
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(data)
```

> this works! But I don't understand why. Can you elaborate?

Sure.

`SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM ...` conceptually equivalent to `SELECT ... GROUP BY`

So, the task was to find appropriate value to GROUP BY and respective Aggregation function (required by GROUP BY)

`ANY_VALUE` and `TO_JSON_STRING(data)` are what we needed here

Comment: Oh wow; this works! But I don't understand why. Can you elaborate?

Also, before I try to work it into my real workflow, does this approach scale? I generally have hundreds of millions of rows.

Comment: sure, added to the answer

Comment: Awesome; thanks! So taking a step back from this problem: am I attacking this "correctly", or are there other/better ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: your approach is good enough so I purposely haven't changed it and rather focused on your main issue - which is deduping output - but there is almost always better way! :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the data you want from the datasets. This query return unique but unnested results:

```
 SELECT data.name, rs.id, r
 FROM data
 left join UNNEST(resultset) rs
 left join UNNEST(results) as r
 JOIN ranges ON r BETWEEN min AND max
```

Comment: That might be a way to eventually go, but it fails on the original condition: I want the full row out if any of the subsubvalues match any of the ranges in table 2: "What I want to end up with is rows from the first table where any result matches one or more of the ranges in the second table"

Comment: You should add the expected result to the question. Makes it easier to work with.